# REGEX - ignore new line characters

Tags: php, regex, email-headers

I came across this line of code:

```
preg_match_all("!boundary=(.*)$!mi", $content, $matches);
```

but for

> Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
>   boundary=f403045e21e067188c05413187fd\r\n

It returns

> f403045e21e067188c05413187fd\r

When it should return

> f403045e21e067188c05413187fd

(without the `\r`)

Any ideas how to fix this?

PS.: It should also work for when `\r` is not present, only `\n`

Comment: Are `\r` and `\n` literal or the new line characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two options.

1. Use lazy dot matching and add an optional `\r`:

   `preg_match_all("!boundary=(.*?)\r?$!mi", $content, $matches);`

See [this PHP demo](http://ideone.com/koyVOT)

2. Use a `[^\r\n]` negated character class matching any char but `\r` and `\n`:

   `preg_match_all("!boundary=([^\n\r]*)!mi", $content, $matches);`

Or, a shorter version, using the `\V` shorthand character class matching any character that is not a vertical whitespace (not a linebreak char):

```
preg_match_all("!boundary=(\V*)!mi", $content, $matches);
```

See [this](http://ideone.com/Y7xs6F) or [this PHP demo](http://ideone.com/KXUx4g).

**Note** that the second approach is much more efficient.

Comment: Right, I was still checking patterns, and only stopped at `\N`. `\V` is also working.

Comment: first one worked fine, didnt try the second. thanks!

Comment: I'd rather recommend the other two options that are faster. I started with the first one as a starter, to show how your pattern could be "fixed".

Comment: as per suggestions, ive switched to `"!boundary=(\V*)!mi"` which is also working fine

Answer (score 0):

Change the expression to

```
preg_match_all("!boundary=(.*)\\r?$!mi", $content, $matches);
```

That should strip out the \r if one exists.

Edited: \r needs escaping in the RegExp.

Comment: This solution [does not work](http://ideone.com/K70iQ4) as the carriage return is still there.